# Heroku React app works in dev, deploys, but doesn't work

Tags: node.js, heroku, npm, deployment, config

App works fine in my dev environment, deploys, but I keep getting an application error.

```
app[web.1]: npm ERR! Exit status 1
app[web.1]: npm ERR!
app[web.1]: npm ERR! Failed at the picklists@1.0.0 start script.
app[web.1]: npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
app[web.1]:
app[web.1]: npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
app[web.1]: npm ERR!     /app/.npm/_logs/2021-03-08T16_18_11_394Z-debug.log
heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1
heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `npm start`
app[web.1]:
app[web.1]: > picklists@1.0.0 start /app
app[web.1]: > node server.js
app[web.1]:
app[web.1]: WARNING: NODE_ENV value of 'production' did not match any deployment config file names.
app[web.1]: WARNING: See https://github.com/lorenwest/node-config/wiki/Strict-Mode
app[web.1]: WARNING: No configurations found in configuration directory:/app/config
app[web.1]: WARNING: To disable this warning set SUPPRESS_NO_CONFIG_WARNING in the environment.
app[web.1]: /app/node_modules/config/lib/config.js:182
app[web.1]: throw new Error('Configuration property "' + property + '" is not defined');
app[web.1]: ^
app[web.1]:
app[web.1]: Error: Configuration property "mongoURI" is not defined
app[web.1]: at Config.get (/app/node_modules/config/lib/config.js:182:11)
app[web.1]: at Object.<anonymous> (/app/config/db.js:3:19)
app[web.1]: at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1015:30)
app[web.1]: at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1035:10)
app[web.1]: at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:879:32)
app[web.1]: at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:724:14)
app[web.1]: at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:903:19)
app[web.1]: at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:74:18)
app[web.1]: at Object.<anonymous> (/app/server.js:2:19)
app[web.1]: at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1015:30)
app[web.1]: at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1035:10)
app[web.1]: at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:879:32)
app[web.1]: at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:724:14)
app[web.1]: at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (internal/modules/run_main.js:60:12)
app[web.1]: at internal/main/run_main_module.js:17:47
app[web.1]: npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
app[web.1]: npm ERR! errno 1
app[web.1]: npm ERR! picklists@1.0.0 start: `node server.js`
app[web.1]: npm ERR! Exit status 1
app[web.1]: npm ERR!
app[web.1]: npm ERR! Failed at the picklists@1.0.0 start script.
app[web.1]: npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
app[web.1]:
app[web.1]: npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
app[web.1]: npm ERR!     /app/.npm/_logs/2021-03-08T16_18_25_458Z-debug.log
heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1
heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
app[api]: Release v18 created by user 
app[api]: Deploy 1d38210b by user 
app[api]: Build succeeded
heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `npm start`
[web.1]:
[web.1]: > picklists@1.0.0 start /app
app[web.1]: > node server.js
app[web.1]:
app[web.1]: WARNING: NODE_ENV value of 'production' did not match any deployment config file names.
app[web.1]: WARNING: See https://github.com/lorenwest/node-config/wiki/Strict-Mode
app[web.1]: WARNING: No configurations found in configuration directory:/app/config
app[web.1]: WARNING: To disable this warning set SUPPRESS_NO_CONFIG_WARNING in the environment.
app[web.1]: /app/node_modules/config/lib/config.js:182
app[web.1]: throw new Error('Configuration property "' + property + '" is not defined');
app[web.1]: ^
app[web.1]:
app[web.1]: Error: Configuration property "MONGO_URI" is not defined
app[web.1]: at Config.get (/app/node_modules/config/lib/config.js:182:11)
app[web.1]: at Object.<anonymous> (/app/config/db.js:3:19)
app[web.1]: at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1015:30)
app[web.1]: at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1035:10)
app[web.1]: at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:879:32)
app[web.1]: at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:724:14)
app[web.1]: at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:903:19)
app[web.1]: at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:74:18)
app[web.1]: at Object.<anonymous> (/app/server.js:2:19)
app[web.1]: at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1015:30)
app[web.1]: at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1035:10)
app[web.1]: at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:879:32)
app[web.1]: at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:724:14)
app[web.1]: at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (internal/modules/run_main.js:60:12)
app[web.1]: at internal/main/run_main_module.js:17:47
app[web.1]: npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
app[web.1]: npm ERR! errno 1
app[web.1]: npm ERR! picklists@1.0.0 start: `node server.js`
app[web.1]: npm ERR! Exit status 1
app[web.1]: npm ERR!
app[web.1]: npm ERR! Failed at the picklists@1.0.0 start script.
app[web.1]: npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
app[web.1]:
app[web.1]: npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
app[web.1]: npm ERR!     /app/.npm/_logs/2021-03-08T16_18_53_202Z-debug.log
heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1
heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=picklists.herokuapp.com status=503 bytes= protocol=https
heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=picklists.herokuapp.com status=503 bytes= protocol=https
heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=picklists.herokuapp.com status=503 bytes= protocol=https
heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=picklists.herokuapp.com status=503 bytes= protocol=https
```

I've tried to reset the dependencies on client and server

```
npm cache clean --force
rm -rf node_modules package-lock.json
npm install
```

I've added a Procfile

```
web:npm start
```

I'm using an env var for the PORT

```
const PORT = process.env.PORT || 5000;

app.listen(PORT, () => {
    console.log(`Server started on port ${PORT}`);
});
```

This is the package.json

```
{
  "name": "picklists",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "engines": {
    "node": "12.x"
  },
  "description": "A MERN app that creates inventory picklists for backstock retrieval",
  "main": "server.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "start": "node server.js",
    "server": "nodemon server.js",
    "client": "npm start --prefix client",
    "clientinstall": "npm install --prefix client",
    "dev": "concurrently \"npm run server\" \"npm run client\"",
    "heroku-postbuild": "NPM_CONFIG_PRODUCTION=false npm install --prefix client && npm run build --prefix client"
  },
  "repository": {
    "type": "git",
    "url": "git+https://github.com/louiswhisenant/picklists.git"
  },
  "author": "Louis Whisenant",
  "license": "ISC",
  "bugs": {
    "url": "https://github.com/louiswhisenant/picklists/issues"
  },
  "homepage": "https://github.com/louiswhisenant/picklists#readme",
  "dependencies": {
    "bcryptjs": "^2.4.3",
    "config": "^3.3.4",
    "express": "^4.17.1",
    "express-validator": "^6.10.0",
    "jsonwebtoken": "^8.5.1",
    "mongoose": "^5.11.19"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "concurrently": "^5.3.0",
    "nodemon": "^2.0.7"
  }
}
```

Env vars are set on heroku. I'm deploying from github instead of the heroku CLI, if that makes any difference.

Also, if references the full debug log at '/app/.npm/_logs/2021-03-08T16_18_11_394Z-debug.log', but I wasn't sure exactly how/where to access that log and see what it says. Can I do it from the terminal, or is it on Heroku?

Comment: Have you been able to fix this? I have the same problem with my jwtSecret.

Comment: Yes! I added dotenv as a dependency, and required it in my config, then called `dotenv.config();` before creating the config object.

[Github](https://github.com/louiswhisenant/picklists) if you want to compare the relevant files to see what might be missing from yours.